# MYSQL error on software

Tags: c++, mysql, character-encoding, collation

I am trying to diagnose a problem on some custom software we had made for us. This is the error I'm getting:

[image: error message]

I have access to the database and tried the following:

```
Changed the database charset to latin1, and collation to latin1_swedish_ci.
But still the same error.
```

Anyone have any clues to what i could do?

Comment: what does this shows on mysql `show variables like "collation_database";`

Comment: Hmm you have already changed it to latin1_swedish_ci, you need to check for the table what collation it is using

Comment: You should really have the error text in the question body rather than a png.  This way others searching for certain keywords can find your question

Comment: the table where the query is executed, you need to set it same as DB collation else you are likely to get this message. From the error message its clear that the table where the query is executed is set as utf8_general_ci better to change the DB collation to utf8_general_ci if most of the tables are with this, u need to check this and set it properly.

Comment: well there are alot of tables, mabey if i change the database collation to utf8, that will work easier?